# How to reference an HTML class tag in code?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have `<td>` elements in my aspx file with assigned classes like this:

```html
<td class="0 1">value1</td>
```

How can I find the text (in this case `"value1"`) of such an element in my code file by using the class tag?

Comment: You need to have runat=server before you can access anything from C#.  Usually you access it by ID

Comment: How is this duplicate. He's asking how to access a class name, not an ID.

Comment: @Pete Adding `runat="server"` won't change the fact that OP might not know how to find `<td class="0 1">`. Adding `runat="server"` is only half the problem. Rocket Science to one, is childplay to another.

Comment: op here, am indeed a noob. Ok I can access it with runat and then getting .CssClass , BUT from where am I searching .CssClass from? do I have to write the id of the td and then add the '.CssClass' part?